# ValueError(errmsg("Extra Data",s,end,len(s))) when using json_loads() twice

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load json data from two files tmp.json and sidebar_order.json by creating file pointers and using json.load or json.loads on them:

```
json_data = open('tmp.json')
data = json.load(json_data)
```

and:

```
menu_data = open('sidebar_order.json').read()
sidebar_data = json.loads(menu_data)
```

but I keep getting the error in the title?

Help please? I have looked at some stackoverflow questions which deal with this error but I cant understand why json.load doesnt work on two different files?

Comment: I got it! It wasn't a case of using it twice at all. Can someone please close the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using it twice wasnt a problem, I had a problem in my sidebar_data.json file which had an unclosed '[' and json thought it had multiple objects which it cant handle.